Connection between general loss functions and the MLE
first up a big disclaimer: This question might already be answered somewhere, so if I have missed it, please just redirect me.
Let $X,Y$ be two (real-valued) random variables. I will assume that their joiny distribution has a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue-measure denoted by $p(x,y)$. Further I will denote the marginals by $p(x), p(y)$ and the conditional by $p(y|x)$.
If we now have some approximation for the conditional $p_\theta(y|x)$ defined by some parameter $\theta \in \Theta$ we can define the MLE as $$\hat{\theta} = \arg\min_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim p(x,y)}\left[-\log(p_\theta(y|x))\right]. $$
In practise, we often assume that there is some functional connection between $X$ and $Y$  in such a case, that is $$Y = g_\phi(\varepsilon,X)$$ for some parameteric function $g_\phi$ with image in $\mathbb{R}$ and a (real-valued) random variable $\varepsilon$ independent of $X$ with $\varepsilon \sim q(\varepsilon)$ (again, assuming it has a density $q$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue-measure). If I am not mistaken, this is often referred to as the reparameterization trick.
Further, in statistical Learning we then define some distance function (usually referred to as loss) $\mathrm{dist}: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and are interested in finding the optimal parameter $$\hat{\phi} = \arg\min_{\phi} \mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim p(x,y), \varepsilon \sim q(\varepsilon)}\left[\mathrm{dist}(y,g_\phi(\varepsilon,x))\right].$$
The connection I am missing, how minimising the expected distance (or risk) relates to the MLE. It appears to me, that the choice of the reparameterization trick should already induce a specific distance function, that should correspond to the MLE. Could someone help me bridging this gap?
Thanks in advance.
